# where can i download OolongEngine?

Tags: iphone, oolong-engine

I have searched the web, but have been unable to find the OolongEngine.zip to download (ie. a link that actually works).
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [project's home page](http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/):

> Please download the source code with a
>   SVN client following the description
>   on the "Source" page. There is no
>   download on the "Downloads" page
>   because it would be too big.

To get the source, from a terminal window, type:

```
svn checkout http://oolongengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ oolongengine-read-only
```

As it says on [this](http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/source/checkout) page.

Comment: Thanks Robot K. I did the svn checkout & got a readout of the source code files on the terminal. I am new to this kind of download though, and I do not know how to convert and begin to use this to code practice.

Comment: i dont know if I should select this as the answer yet...!

Comment: Well, downloading the code and being able to use it are two different things. Based on this post(http://maniacdev.com/2009/08/the-open-source-iphone-game-engine-comparison/), it sounds like getting up and running with Oolong can be pretty difficult. I would start by joining the project's mailing list (http://lists.oolongengine.com/listinfo.cgi/oolong-oolongengine.com) and asking for advice there.